# Error writing my cv using moderncv document class

Tags: errors, moderncv, cv

I need to know what is the wrong with this template...

I used it before but now is not working

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}% Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'

\makeatother
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Asmaa} % Your first name
\familyname{Masoud} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address}
\phone{}

\email{}
% The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example

\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{pictures/mio} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
\quote{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}
\cventry{2014--present}{enrolled in a PHD program in my home university, also passed a one year of preparing subjects}
\cventry{2011--2013}{ Masters in Electronics Engineering Universitat Rovira i Virgili}{\textit{GPA -- 8.35} 
\cventry{2005--2010}{Bachelor in Electronics Engineering}{The University of Benha}{BHIT-"Benha Higher Institute of Technology}{\textit{GPA -- 8.5}}{First Class Honours, Specialized in Communications}
\section{Masters Thesis}
\cvitem{Title}{\emph{Extension to high temperature and applications of a high frequency Double-Gate MOSFET model to Thz detection.}}
\cvitem{Supervisors}{Professor  Benjamin Iniguez .}
\cvitem{Description}{This thesis was a study on the Behaviour of DG mosfet in simulation for High-Temperature/High-Frequency Behaviour in low power applications.}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{2010--Present}{3 Years administrator}{\textsc{Benha university}}{Egypt}{Being responsible for solving problems with students and teaching them techniques for solving.
\newline \newline
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to control group of student almost my age
\item had fare enough experience with teaching
\end{itemize}
%------------------------------------------------
\cventry{OCT 2010--DEC 2011}{Safety Engineer}{\textsc{Softrose Company}}{ Zahra l maday,Cairo,Egypt
}{ Working for two months as a safety engineer specially responsible for the behaviour of machines, was a short period job immediately after graduation.}
%------------------------------------------------
\cventry{AUG 2007--SEP 2007}{private course}{\textsc{ Jelecom (panasonic) }}{ 26 july st,Cairo,Egypt}{}{In my third year of Engineering.
\newline \newline
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction about microprocessors
\item 89c52 assembly language programming
\item  Hardware projects related to the course  
\end{itemize}
%--------------------------------------------------
\cventry{JULY-2007}{Summer training}{\textsc{Toshiba El Araby factory}}{ Benha,Egypt}{}{In my third year of Engineering.}
\newline \newline
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Transformers making
\item Ac and Dc motors design 
\item Manufacturing from core material
  \end{itemize}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Awards}
\cvitem{2009}{The DAAD traineeships for two months to do summer training in Bremen, Germany}
\cvitem{2011}{The URV (University Rovira I Virgili) international master scholarship for one year  master degree in Electronic Engineering, Tarragona, Spain }
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Computer skills}
\cvitem{Basic}{\textsc{java}, Mathematica}
\cvitem{Intermediate}{\LaTeX, OpenOffice, Microsoft Windows}
\cvitem{Advanced}{Matlab, Assembly, C++}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Communication Skills}
\cvitem {Ability to work under stress and meeting deadlines effectively.}
\cvitem{Very good at self study.} 
\cvitem{Ability to work individually or as part of a team.}
\cvitem{Ambitious, Hard worker.}
\cvitem{Ability to cope with new situations fast.}
\cvitem{Seeking challenges and having the ability to overcome the difficulties.} 
\cvitem{Excellent communication and interpersonal skills.}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Arabic}{Mother tongue}
\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Fluent}{TOEFL score 85 with writing score 25}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{Intermediate}
\cvitemwithcomment{French}{Basic}{Basic words and phrases only}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newpage 
\section{Interests}
\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists
\cvlistdoubleitem{Writing poems}{Reading}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Cooking}{drawing}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Running}{listening to music}
%------------------------------------------------------
%%%educational interests
%-------------------------------------------------------
\section{Educational Interests}
\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~}
\cvitem {}{PHotonic crystlas and their applications}
\cvitem {}{Nano-Technology modelling }
\cvitem{} {C++ programming}
\cvitem{}{ Mathematical modelling}
\cvitem{}{ Embedded systems}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COVER LETTER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example minimal.

Comment: I would advise modifying the code in your question to remove any personal information if you haven't already.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `moderncv` as I don't use it, but for one, the command `\cventry` takes *seven* arguments: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7804.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you supply the wrong number of arguments.

- `\cventry` needs 6 arguments.
- `\cvitem` needs 2 arguments.
- `\cvitemwithcomment` needs 3 arguments.

I tried to fix it, but I'm not sure that everything ended up in the correct argument.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}% Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'

\makeatother
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Asmaa} % Your first name
\familyname{Masoud} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{37 Stadium street}{Benha, Egypt}
\mobile{(002) 0106 4840127}
\phone{(002) 0133 243777}

\email{asmaa.mas3oud@gmail.com}
% The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example

\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{pictures/mio} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
\quote{"The distance between your existence and realizing your existence is far beyond infinity" - Asmaa Masoud}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}
\cventry{2014--present}{enrolled in a PHD program in my home university, also passed a one year of preparing subjects}{}{}{}{}
\cventry{2011--2013}{Masters in Electronics Engineering Universitat Rovira i Virgili}{\textit{GPA -- 8.35}}{}{}{} 
\cventry{2005--2010}{Bachelor in Electronics Engineering}{The University of Benha}{BHIT-"Benha Higher Institute of Technology}{\textit{GPA -- 8.5}}{First Class Honours, Specialized in Communications}
\section{Masters Thesis}
\cvitem{Title}{\emph{Extension to high temperature and applications of a high frequency Double-Gate MOSFET model to Thz detection.}}
\cvitem{Supervisors}{Professor  Benjamin Iniguez .}
\cvitem{Description}{This thesis was a study on the Behaviour of DG mosfet in simulation for High-Temperature/High-Frequency Behaviour in low power applications.}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{2010--Present}{3 Years administrator}{\textsc{Benha university}}{Egypt}{Being responsible for solving problems with students and teaching them techniques for solving.}{%
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to control group of student almost my age
\item had fare enough experience with teaching
\end{itemize}%
}
%------------------------------------------------
\cventry{OCT 2010--DEC 2011}{Safety Engineer}{\textsc{Softrose Company}}{ Zahra l maday,Cairo,Egypt
}{ Working for two months as a safety engineer specially responsible for the behaviour of machines, was a short period job immediately after graduation.}{}
%------------------------------------------------
\cventry{AUG 2007--SEP 2007}{private course}{\textsc{ Jelecom (panasonic) }}{ 26 july st,Cairo,Egypt}{In my third year of Engineering.}{%
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction about microprocessors
\item 89c52 assembly language programming
\item  Hardware projects related to the course  
\end{itemize}%
}
%--------------------------------------------------
\cventry{JULY-2007}{Summer training}{\textsc{Toshiba El Araby factory}}{ Benha,Egypt}{In my third year of Engineering.}{%
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Transformers making
\item Ac and Dc motors design 
\item Manufacturing from core material
  \end{itemize}%
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Awards}
\cvitem{2009}{The DAAD traineeships for two months to do summer training in Bremen, Germany}
\cvitem{2011}{The URV (University Rovira I Virgili) international master scholarship for one year  master degree in Electronic Engineering, Tarragona, Spain }
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Computer skills}
\cvitem{Basic}{\textsc{java}, Mathematica}
\cvitem{Intermediate}{\LaTeX, OpenOffice, Microsoft Windows}
\cvitem{Advanced}{Matlab, Assembly, C++}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Communication Skills}
\cvitem{}{Ability to work under stress and meeting deadlines effectively.}
\cvitem{}{Very good at self study.}
\cvitem{}{Ability to work individually or as part of a team.}
\cvitem{}{Ambitious, Hard worker.}
\cvitem{}{Ability to cope with new situations fast.}
\cvitem{}{Seeking challenges and having the ability to overcome the difficulties.}
\cvitem{}{Excellent communication and interpersonal skills.}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Arabic}{Mother tongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Fluent}{TOEFL score 85 with writing score 25}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{Intermediate}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{French}{Basic}{Basic words and phrases only}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newpage 
\section{Interests}
\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists
\cvlistdoubleitem{Writing poems}{Reading}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Cooking}{drawing}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Running}{listening to music}
%------------------------------------------------------
%%%educational interests
%-------------------------------------------------------
\section{Educational Interests}
\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~}
\cvitem {}{PHotonic crystlas and their applications}
\cvitem {}{Nano-Technology modelling }
\cvitem{} {C++ programming}
\cvitem{}{ Mathematical modelling}
\cvitem{}{ Embedded systems}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COVER LETTER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```